# APA Citation on online documentation

Tags: citations, apa

I am referencing the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html) in a paper. Would it be appropriate to reference it in its entirety, or should I create a citation for each page I use since it's very large?

Answer (score 1):

Cite this work as:

> Axmark, D., & Widenius, M. (2015). *MySQL 5.7 reference manual.* Redwood Shores, CA: Oracle. Available online at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html

Since there are no page numbers, give web page headings in text:

> Bla bla bla (Axmark & Widenius, 2015, 9.4 User-Defined Variables). Bla bla bla.

Comment: I recommend referencing the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/) site for questions about citations in APA style. It got me through my Masters' coursework without a misstep.